# How to open MDI form under MDI Main Form in C#

Tags: c#

I have total 3 form

1. frmMain
2. frmA
3. frmB

frmMain and frmA both have MDI container and frmB is normal form. I want to Open frmA under frmMain MDI and then frmB under frmA MDI.

Below is code that open frmA form from frmMain .

```
`frmA tempObj = new frmA(); 
tempObj.MdiParent = this; //error here- Form cannot be both an MDI child and MDI parent. 
tempObj.ShowIcon = false; 
tempObj.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; 
tempObj.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
tempObj.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; 
tempObj.Show(); `
```

frmMain is startup form.

Comment: What have you tried already? And did you encounter any issues or problems with your attempts? It would be great if you could add your attempt with the corresponding [mcve] code

Comment: Dear Sir ,
Below is code that open frmA form . 
frmA tempObj = new frmA();
tempObj.MdiParent = this; //error here- Form cannot be both an MDI child and MDI parent. 
tempObj.ShowIcon = false;
tempObj.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
tempObj.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tempObj.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
tempObj.Show();

Comment: Instead of commentig please [edit] your question and update it with your code properly formatted in markdown

Comment: I have edit my question,

Comment: `frmMain and frmA both have MDI container`  You can't put an MDI container inside an MDI container.